# Angular: apply ngif out of a tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have to iterate an array of images that are shown in the view. every 3 images a specific div is applied.
Manually I have been doing it like this:

```
<div class="logos w-slider" data-animation="fade" data-autoplay="1" data-delay="4000" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1">
  <div class="w-slider-mask">
    <br>
    <div class="w-slide">
      <div class="clientes w-row" align="center">
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 18%; height: 100%; text-align:center;"><img src="assets/assets/img/postgres.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/php2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/serversql.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slide">
      <div class="clientes w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 18%; height: 100%; text-align:center;"><img src="assets/img/hibernate.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/java2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/jquery.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/json.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slide">
      <div class="clientes w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 18%; height: 100%; text-align:center;"><img src="assets/img/bootstrap-logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/typescript.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4" style="float:left; width: 16%; height: 100%;"><img src="assets/img/ajax.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I want to put those images in a file and then run it dynamically using angular. The problem is that certain div I have to use only every 3, but I do not know how to do it, since ngIf does not work for me.

I wanted to know if Angular has any way of doing this.

In PHP I used something like this:

@if(condition)
   here I would add the div
@endif

here I would iterate the images

@if(condition)
   here would close the div
@endif

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`*ngFor="let img of imgs; let i = index"`

Then you can use the i variable to detect if it is the 3rd, using

`(i+1) % 3 === 0`

as i is zero indexed, using this boolean, you can apply a class, or another div using *ngIf

Comment: The problem with this is that ngif is applied from opening to closing. I need to add some div only when that condition is met, but there is a div (the one that shows the image) that always goes

Comment: I don't fully understand, are you sure there's not another approach you could take? maybe using css background-img or something similar?

Comment: I would advice to prepare data-structure first (make object there each key valued with array with three images) and then use two nested ngFor directives (first by object keys, second by this key values)